# Reactjs: How to clear text field after submission

Tags: reactjs, backend

I have a signup page which has 4 input text fields which changes the currentState of each field from an empty string to whatever I inputted. After signing up it logs each of the following 4 fields input in a database with a post request. How can I clear each field after clicking on the sign up button. Basically I just want the page to clear after clicking. I have attempted to set the state of the 4 variables back to an empty string at the end of my promise chain but nothing changes still.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import style from './Signup.css';
import Axios from 'axios';

function Signup() {
  
  const [firstReg, setFirstNameReg] = useState('')
  const [lastReg, setLastNameReg] = useState('')
  const [emailReg, setEmailReg] = useState('')
  const [passReg, setPassReg] = useState('')

  const register = () => {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/register', {
      first_name: firstReg,
      last_name: lastReg,
      email: emailReg,
      password: passReg,
    }).then((response)=> {
      console.log(response);
      setFirstNameReg('')
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="Signup">    
      <div className='Sign'>
      <div class="photo"> Create an account</div>
        <div class ='searche'>
          <div className="searchInputse">
                    <input type="text" onChange={(e)=> {setFirstNameReg(e.target.value)}} placeholder={'First name'} />
                    <div className="searchIcone"></div>
                </div>
                <div className="dataResult"></div>
        </div>
        <div class ='searche'>
          <div className="searchInputse">
                    <input type="text" onChange={(e)=> {setLastNameReg(e.target.value)}} placeholder={'Last name'}/>
                    <div className="searchIcone"></div>
                </div>
                <div className="dataResult"></div>
        </div>
        <div class ='searche'>
          <div className="searchInputse">
                    <input type="text" onChange={(e)=> {setEmailReg(e.target.value)}} placeholder={'Email'}/>
                    <div className="searchIcone"></div>
                </div>
                <div className="dataResult"></div>
        </div>
        <div class ='searche'>
          <div className="searchInputse">
                    <input type="text" onChange={(e)=> {setPassReg(e.target.value)}} placeholder={'Password'}/>
                    <div className="searchIcone"></div>
                </div>
                <div className="dataResult"></div>
        </div>
        <button className='searchee' onClick={register}>
          Sign Up
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default Signup;
```

Comment: Try adding a `.catch()`  to see if there's an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things you should be aware of.

1st. You want to keep your data in an object for easy management and code reduction like so:

Define the initial object outside of your component;

```js
let initialValues = {
  'first_name': '',
  'last_name': '',
  'email': '',
}
```

And inside your component define state with the `initialValues` variable as the state default.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(initialValues);
```

And then, in your JSX you can connect the values with the object keys like so:

```html
<input type="text" name="first_name" value={data.first_name} />
<input type="text" name="last_name" value={data.last_name} />
<input type="text" name="email" value={data.email} />
```

You can also then add an onChange handler to that input like so:
`note:` name must match the key inside of the `initalValues` object.

```html
<input type="text" name="first_name" value={data.first_name} onChange={handleChange} />
<input type="text" name="last_name" value={data.last_name} onChange={handleChange} />
<input type="text" name="email" value={data.email} onChange={handleChange} />
```

`handleChange` basic function can look like this:

```js
const onChange = (e) => {
  setData({...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

Essentially all you're doing is typing inside the input field, `onChange` detects a change on each key press, and fires off the `handleChange` function, that function makes a copy of the current state of `data` then looks at the `e.target.name` which could be `first_name` and sets it to `e.target.value` which is anything you type.

That way, all you need to pass to axios is the data object.

I hope this helps, let me know if you have any other questions.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to  replace  your register button with  this :

```html
<button className='searchee' onClick={()=>{register();setFirstNameReg('');setLastNameReg('');setEmailReg('');setPassReg('')}}>
  Sign Up
</button>
```